# How to compress only SDE.DEFAULT version of a geodatabase?

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase, esri-geodatabase, versioning, compression

I'm new to GIS administration, specifically geodatabase administration. When I started my current job, the previous administrators had performed a partial compression of the SDE geodatabase. I work with ArcGIS 10.8 versioned SDE Geodatabase. They needed to compress only the SDE.DEFAULT version (with already applied and published edits there), without simultaneously closing (reconciling) some other active versions.

As far as I know, in ArcMap, there is only a way to perform a full compression. However, it's not considered good practice to perform partial compression (only for SDE.DEFAULT).

Nonetheless, it is crucial not to close/reconcile the open versions and to compress the SDE.DEFAULT because the system starts to work slowly. I know it's not a common problem, but I need help, because the previous administrators wont help me. Please, give me ideas how to do it. ArcPy or ArcMap interface/tools? I have a testing environment, so I can test the solution.